# Windows 8.1 bootloader is not working after install Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

after installing Ubuntu 14.04 windows boot loader is not opening  ... when i turn on my laptop it boot directly ubuntu . There is no option to boot windows boot loader. I didnot delete or format any partition when i installed ubuntu. I cannot mount the windows partition on ubuntu either. What can I do now ?

Comment: First of all tell us what type of installation did you use? UEFI or BIOS mode, both for Windows and Ubuntu.
Second - maybe you'll be able to load windows through F8 boot menu.

Comment: did you try grub repair? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: This would be your first stop ^^^

Answer (score 0):

If you can not see the menu of GRUB on start up, you've to type the shift button of your keyboard when you're turning on you laptop

If you to fix it you've to edit /etc/default/grub file in sudo mode and modify the following line like this :

`# GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`

Don't forget to update your grub with this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: can u  provide the command of editing grub file

Comment: Why are we editing the grub file this is not the best idea

Comment: then how can i boot windows ?   I need to load windows boot loader

Comment: I have a solution

Comment: here is the link                                                                                                                         http://askubuntu.com/questions/725290/grub-windows-10-doesnt-start-anymore/725309#725309

Comment: Edit the file in case that the first step is working. So you got the GRUB menu with the shit button down during the start up . As you didn't tell us what's king of environment you're using. So it's depend could be gedit for gnome, xcfe , kate for KDE , vim in your terminal.... You've to put sudo before the soft you want to use