# How to fix Windows 10 Boot error while dual booting throuh Grub2

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I recently Installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 on my Lenovo Ideapad Z500 laptop.

The laptop came with Windows 8 pre installed, which I upgraded to Windows 8.1 and then to Windows 10.

I am new to Linux and don't have much experience with it.

I have installed both OS successfully and the boot menu(grub) is loading properly displaying both Linux and Windows along with some other options:

[Grub Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCI1T.jpg)

The problem is that When I boot up my machine, the grub boot menu is displayed, but when I try to boot Windows using that, it gives me the following Error:

[Boot Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfma8.jpg)

I am able to boot into Ubuntu normally and also able to boot into windows, if I Boot via the "one-click recovery" button and choosing the windows loader from the boot options:

So, both OS are installed fine and booting correctly. The only problem is that windows does not boot via the grub menu.

I have already tried doing the steps suggested in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725290/grub-windows-10-doesnt-start-anymore), but it didn't fix the problem.

I have also tried putting the Windows boot loader first by changing the UEFI setting to UEFI only. But that just loads the windows 10 OS without going to grub or Ubuntu. So Ubuntu can't load that way.

My Machine uses UEFI instead of the old BIOS system.

Is there any way to fix this, without reformatting my entire system and installing Ubuntu first and then Windows on top of it.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here's what happened: The factory installed Windows was, as expected, installed in UEFI mode but you then installed Ubuntu in Legacy. As such there's no other way to dual-boot than the one you found already by switching modes at UEFI.

Comment: Is there a way to install Ubuntu 16.04 in UEFI mode?
Would that work normally with dual boot?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI