# windows 10 image not found in grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a problem booting Windows 10 from grub. When I tried to do it I got this message:

```
/EndEntire
file path: /ACPI....../File(bootmgfw.efi)/EndEntire
error: cannot load image.
```

I then Googled and found this [solved problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725290/grub-windows-10-doesnt-start-anymore?newreg=404946410b0542f08db79a5b31087ccc), which tells you to edit the `grub.cfg` file.

> Edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
>
> Find
>
> `### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###`
>
> `menuentry 'Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sdXX)'`
>
> After
>
> `chainloader +1`
>
> Write
>
> `ntldr /bootmgr`

When I tried to apply that I got this error, in addition to the original one

```
error: can't find command `ntldr'.
```

This might be due to my `grub.cfg` file not looking like the one in the link but I don't know how to adapt the solution.

As the `grub.cfg` file is quite lengthy, this is the section mentioned in the other solution.

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class     os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-4CBE-1366' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-    efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  4CBE-1366
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4CBE-1366
    fi
        chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
    }
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
```

The full file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8YWT6Jkf0jRTGZZRGFyMUpKTVk/view?usp=sharing) if needed.

I've tried to update grub, no difference.

**Edit:**

Output from terminal

```
kajsa@Yoga ~ $ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for kajsa: 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo update-grub` ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the exact commands you tried. What gave you the `ntldr` error?  What does your `grub.cfg` look like? Also what Ravexina said: did you run `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: @Ravexina, yes I have, did not change anything

Comment: @terdon, I've added the information you suggested. Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: @terdon, Added the output, still get the original error message.