# Grub cannot boot to windows saying error: cannot load image

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a dual boot of Ubuntu (20.04) and Windows 11 on a single ssd. Everything worked fine, but suddenly (that is without any change in configurations I am aware of, any update I am aware of or anything like that), I cannot load into windows. I see the same options in the boot menu as before, but when I try to boot into windows, it just says "error: cannot load image".

What I tried so far:

sudo update-grub returns

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-87-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-87-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-84-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-84-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

and fixes nothing

Os prober on the windows partition returns

```
dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
```

and also fixes nothing.

Trying to troubleshoot the windows installation from a usb installation image also says, that the repair failed and restoring to a point before last update (about a week ago, worked in between) also didn't help.

I found this question: [windows 10 image not found in grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920303/windows-10-image-not-found-in-grub) and have very similar results

I can access all the data from the Ubuntu partition, even during the repair process from the installation flash drive everything seemed to be fine on the side of windows, but for some reason, I just cannot boot into it. Any ideas what could be wrong and how to fix it?

EDIT1: when I try to boot into windows using windows boot manager, it starts with a hardware scan and then says that there are no bootable devices. Seems like the issue is not on the side of grub/Ubuntu, but that is where I am trying to fix it from, since I don't have access elsewhere.

Comment: The Windows "Fast Boot" setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on.

Comment: @waltinator I cannot boot into windows at all, I cannot do that. Also I would think that this would get fixed by restoring windows to some previous point which I tried.