# Cannot boot into Windows 10 after upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, upgrade

I noticed that whenever I try to select "Windows 10" from the grub boot screen, it turns black and then returns to Grub.

This happened after I upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS.  I should note that I triple boot with Mac OSX High Sierra and chainload Clover from Grub.  I also noticed that Clover does not detect Windows 10 as a bootable option anymore.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going on?

I have tried:

1. sudo update-grub
2. boot-repair

Nothing seemed to work.  Any ideas?

Here is my boot-repair pastebin
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jrzcMYk9WG/

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `boot-repair` yet?

Comment: Yes, boot-repair does not fix the issue.  Here is my pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jrzcMYk9WG/ - The issue is that when I select Windows 10, the screen goes black and immediately goes back to the GRUB screen without any error.

Comment: It looks like you somehow overwrote the first sector of your Windows partition with an instance of Grub. You will need a Windows DVD to repair your Windows installation.

Comment: I've tried bootrec /fixboot and that does not work.  It gives me access denied.  I still have the same problem only now it says, "GRUB LOADING" before returning back to grub.  How do I repair my first sector of my Windows Partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get Windows to boot!!!

Ok here is what I did to fix it:

1. I launched a Windows Installer USB and entered the command line
2. I ran bootrec /rebuildbcd to fix my BCD then
3. bootsect /nt60 C: /force <-- This clears GRUB from the NTFS Boot sector
4. Then GRUB couldn't boot Windows, it just went to a black screen with a DOS cursor
5. To fix this I had to add: ntldr /bootmgr after chainloader +1 in my /boot/grub/grub.cfg

The GRUB fix is here:
[*Grub* Windows 10 doesn't start anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725290/grub-windows-10-doesnt-start-anymore)