# *dual boot* windows didn't do anything after selected in grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

my problem prety much same like this thread [*Grub* Windows 10 doesn't start anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725290/grub-windows-10-doesnt-start-anymore)
i've tried the solution on that post but i can't find any chainloader +1 there and if in my file is another chainloader i've tried to enter the ntldr /bootmgr after that chainloader and the result when i chose it the screen after that is windows can't find ntldr. what should i do to fix this problem?

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows & that also means fast start up must be off. That is most common issue. But if you did not install Ubuntu in same boot mode, probably UEFI as Windows then that is a major issue. Please attach link to the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  & http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: hey thanks for answering my question, i'm prety sure i already turn off the fast start up. i installed ubuntu in same drive as windows but different partition. where i can get the summary report you? thanks

Comment: If you use your Ubuntu live installer & add Boot-Repair & run report as explained in link above, it will give you a link to a pastebin site. Post that link.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8HhPfpJdF6/ is it what you mean? but i'm not using cdlive, i'm using elementary os that already install in my computer

Comment: This is an Ubuntu forum, we do not know differences with other versions even if based on Ubuntu. But you have sdb as UEFI boot for both Windows & Elementary. But sda has a BIOS boot of Windows. And you may have UEFI Secure Boot on. You also have BIOS boot versions of grub in MBR of both drives that will not work. Install a Windows boot loader to sda. and always boot sdb in UEFI boot mode.  But you can only boot sda from UEFI/BIOS in BIOS mode.