# grub Can't open windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows, windows-7

Background : I am a windows user and i just want to use dualboot windows 7 and ubuntu, and my pc is so old, cause i heard that ubuntu is lightweight and i want to give it a try, i have an old hdd with 3 partitions, and when i install linux, it has 4 now, i allocated 45gb to linux

So everytime i try to open windows with grub, it just goes to grub the screen again and i tried a couple times but it still wont boot to windows, i already tried the `sudo update-grub` on the terminal, i checked the file explorer and there is still my windows folder, and when i updated grub it says `Found Windows 7 on /dev/sda1`. and i also made a copy of the 04_custom file on `etc/grub.d/04_custom` to add a menuentry which i copied this from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus), i also made a copy of the 04_custom file and added a menuentry from grub.cfg (i named the file "06_name" for the one i copied from ubuntu forums and "07_name" for the ones i copied from grub.cfg, and because it says i can name it everything in [Here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2305787&p=13404285#post13404285)) and i updated grub. but i still can't acess Windows. heres what my 07_name looks like

i also tried adding `ntldr /bootmgr` after `chainloader +1` in [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725290/windows-doesnt-start-anymore-from-the-grub-boot-menu) in the menu entry that looks like this ( copied from my grub.cfg ) `### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 7 (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-38D470B7D47078C8' {` but still, everytime i try to open windows with grub, it just goes back to the grub screen again

and i ALSO used boot repair, here is the code

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

but.. it still doesn't work

So what am i gonna do?, im a complete newbie to linux, i watch lots of tutorial videos.
well if it still doesn't works, might as well reinstall windows :(

If you read all of this, thank you!, sorry for my bad english...
any more questions?, i will try my best to awnser it nicely.
If you have any solutions, please awnser, and sorry if what i told you is incomplete in some way

Thank you for helping me:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)