# I can't boot into Windows 10 from GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-10

I bought a new SSD, but since my computer had only one SSD slot, I removed my old SSD and inserted the new one. I installed Windows 10, then I installed Ubuntu, I set it to boot into Ubuntu from Easy BCD, but I turned off the boot selection menu, so the computer boots into Ubuntu as soon as it is turned on. I thought I could boot into Windows from the menu that appears(GRUB) at startup in Ubuntu, but when I try to boot into Windows it goes back to the Ubuntu boot menu.

I couldn't solve my problem elsewhere, so I wanted to open a new question.

Comment: @karel Thank you. I have not seen this before. I think it will help me, but I cannot select the repair windows files option. There was a solution in the post you sent for this, but it did not work for me.

Comment: You have storage media like an external hard drive for backing up your Windows personal files I hope.

Comment: Is there any solution to this other than reinstalling Windows? And besides, I install the Windows new, I only installed Chrome and I don't have any personal files.

Answer (score -1):

Try `sudo update-grub` to rebuild grub's understanding of your configuration post installation/update.

Also see https://askubuntu.com/a/729752/405461

Comment: I've seen this before and tried it but it didn't work for me

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to the problem, but another problem arose. First, let me explain how I solved my problem.

I selected the repair your computer option on the Windows installation disk and opened CMD from the repair section from there. I wrote the following commands there:

```
bootrec /fixMBR
bootrec /fixBoot
bootrec /rebuild BCD
```

after that I was able to boot into Windows via GRUB.

The problem is that the video card does not appear in the device manager and the keyboard does not work. (This is a problem related to Windows 10, I'm not sure if I should write here)